# jqgird. how to change form field names?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid to represent my data. I added a form to my grid. when jqgrid are posting data to server, I want to change the name of the field.
ex:

```
{name:'istenenDepo.adi', index:'istenenDepo.adi',editable:true,
                   editable: true,
                   edittype:"select",
                editoptions:{
                    value:"#{list items:depoList, as:'depo'}${depo.id}:${depo};#{/list}",
                    dataEvents: [
                  {  type: 'change',
                     fn: function(e) {
                        $('input#istenenDepoId').val(this.value);
                     }
                  }
               ]
                },
                formoptions:{
                    elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                }
            }
```

Normally it sends data to server with the field name of istenenDepo.id, but I want to change it like malzemeIstek.istenenDepo.id.
ex:
it post like

```
myurl?istenenDepo.adi=1&isteyenDepo.adi=1&istekZamani=2011-09-08&isteyenKullanici=fyfry&istenenDepo.id=&isteyenDepoId=1&oper=add&id=_empty
```

but we want

```
myurl?malzemeIstek.istenenDepo.adi=1&malzemeIstek.isteyenDepo.adi=1&malzemeIstek.istekZamani=2011-09-08&malzemeIstek.isteyenKullanici=fyfry&malzemeIstek.istenenDepo.id=&malzemeIstek.isteyenDepoId=1&oper=add&id=_empty
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use any special character like points in the column name (see `name:'istenenDepo.adi'`). The event [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) (see the answer from **isntn**) allow you full customization of the data send to the server. The event can return object with the properties which will be seen as the parameters. The parameter of the `serializeEditData` is the object with *original* properties and the values which should be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use serializeEditData event which is fired before post and it allows you to mingle with data to be posted.

To quote docs:-

*If set this event can serialize the data passed to the ajax request when we save a form data. The function should return the serialized data. This event can be used when a custom data should be passed to the server - e.g - JSON string, XML string and etc. To this event is passed the data which will be posted to the server.*

Please look [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) for more information.